# What is the reason for this Perl formatting error?

Tags: perl

```
$str =sprintf "%014ld", "2555600000";
print $str;
```

This gives me the result:

```
-0001739367296
```

a negative number. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: It doesn't for me.  Are you working on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: yes but the similar code run in java gave me correct result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`2555600000` is too big to fit in a 32-bit signed integer.
Converted to binary, it's `10011000 01010011 01011100 10000000`, which stands for `-0001739367296` when interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer.

Your options are:

```
my $str = sprintf("%014u", 2555600000);     # unsigned integer
my $str = sprintf("%014.0f", 2555600000);   # floating point
my $str = sprintf("%014s", 2555600000);     # string
```

The first one works for this number, but not for much higher numbers.  The second one can become inaccurate for very high numbers.  (But with the standard floating point "double" you should easily be accurate for the 14 digits you're using.  The third one might be the easiest, just treat it as a string and forget that it's a number.

To see how many bits your version is using, you can run `perl -V`.  Example output:

```
...
intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
...
```

so my Perl is using 4-byte, 32-bit, integers.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -e '$str =sprintf "%014ld", "2555600000"; print $str, "\n";'
00002555600000
```

It works for me.  However, the number you give is bigger than a 32 bit signed integer can hold, so maybe your result means you're on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: 32-bit Perl it is. Not the machine.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the printf modifiers are fairly tightly coupled to underlying C types (though the sizes are determined by perl - ld is no different than d, underneath, perl will use the qualifier size of int it is built for).

So %d will convert a number to a signed int, %u to an unsigned int, even if perl knows which it actually is.

You are often better off just using %s:

```
$ perl -wle'printf "%014s\n%014d\n", "2555600000", "2555600000";'
00002555600000
-0001739367296
```

Comment: +1 for using `%014s`.  I stole it and added it to my answer.  :-)